# Setting up tor with selenium web driver. (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, tor

i have tried to set up my tor with selenium but it continuously throws up exceptions.

I have tried setting up the binary as well as profiles but no luck.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\Jawad Ahmad Khan\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe')
profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\Jawad Ahmad Khan\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, 
executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
```

This is the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure&u=https%3A//check.torproject.org/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20proxy%20server%20that%20is%20refusing%20connections.
```

Comment: Do you have the correct port?  The default is 9150.

Comment: can you please explain a bit.

Comment: check -- tor:about:preferences:network proxy:settings:sock port

Comment: and is tor running on your system when you make this selenium request?

Comment: yes tor is running on my system, browser instance opens up but then time out exception with this error occurs.

Comment: i figured it out when i comment this line of code: profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False) every thing works fine. But i do not know why, If you can input something about that you are very welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure about set_preference ("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False, because that is for firefox.

Comment: I'm auditing my old answers.  Did my answer on this question help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my Mac with Chrome with Tor.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def get_chrome_webdriver():

  tor_proxy = "127.0.0.1:9150"

  chrome_options = Options()
  chrome_options.add_argument("--test-type")
  chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
  chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://%s' % tor_proxy)

  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

  return driver

def get_chrome_browser(url):
  browser = get_chrome_webdriver()
  browser.get(url)

  return browser


get_chrome_browser('https://check.torproject.org/')
```

Comment: I can confirm it works on Windows 10, with the sole exception of removing first param to webdriver.Chrome